# Are there more than 12 golden keys in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

I think that the King of the Underworld Mard Geer and the Celestial Spirit King fight more than 1 fights because in episode 249 Mard Geer said to the Celestial Spirit King "I don't believe I will lose to you this time, either."

[image: Screencap of Mrd Geer saying the dialog in episode 249]

but it's impossible for Mard Geer to go to the Celestial World, so I believe that a golden key or more was destroyed before Aquarius.

Are there more than 12 golden keys?

Comment: Well, technically there are 13 gates, so yeah, there are more than 12 golden keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Keys regenerate in time. This is confirmed early on into the final major arc of the manga, which has yet to start in the rebooted Fairy Tail Final Season Anime, but this is minor spoilers

https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Aquarius in the Alvarez Empire Arc

> A year later, Aquarius reappears (of her own accord) from a spilled vase of water, saving Lucy from the wrath of (Spoiler)....Aquarius then proceeds to happily embrace Lucy, and explains that another Water Bearer key has surfaced somewhere in the world, and that the Celestial Spirit King opened her gate temporarily, which allowed her to save her

So its likely that someone did sacrifice the key to summon him, and then later on the key regenerated and reentered circulation.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are only 12 for the 12 zodiac signs. They are one of a kind, so there is only ever one key that can exist for each zodiac.

Comment: Then how mard geer and celestial king met before ?

Comment: In the episode where Lucy got Leo she did not summon the celestial king like most spirits he can open his gate himself so he probably felt a disturbance in the magic and came face to face with mardgeer and even if a key is broken it is remade and is thrown back into the world and the person who wants the key has to go and refined it

Comment: Is that mean that a new key will appear instead of aquarius key ?

Comment: Are you reading the manga or watching the anime because if so spoilers would you like to hear them

Comment: Actually, there are 13, not 12. You're forgetting the 13th gate belonging to Yukino Agria, the Gate of the Snake Charmer, Ophiuchus.

Answer (score 0):

SPOILERS (Unless you about finished the 2009 series)

Yes. In the 164th episode of the 2009 series, a character uses a golden key that unleashes the star constellation Ophiuchus, aka the serpent charmer. Yes, the golden keys are all zodiacs, but Ophiuchus is an exception. Ophiuchus is pronounced as (Oh-Fyoo-Shiss)